# How to save a specific part of a JPanel?

Tags: java, jpanel, chess

I am working on a chess game and I would like to let the player choose the board's colors. Therefore I will use this method:

```
    static void createBoard(Graphics g) {

    Color bright = new Color(255, 225, 181);    //player chooses color
    Color dark = new Color(188, 141, 105);      //player chooses color
    boolean darkTile = false;

    for (int y = spaceY; y < (spaceY + BOARDHEIGHT); y += TILESIZE) {
        for (int x = spaceX; x < (spaceX + BOARDWIDTH); x += TILESIZE) {
            if (darkTile) {
                g.setColor(dark);
            } else {
                g.setColor(bright);
            }
            g.fillRect(x, y, TILESIZE, TILESIZE);
            darkTile = !darkTile;
        }
        darkTile = !darkTile;
    }
    BufferedImage overlay;
    try {
        overlay = ImageIO.read(new File("overlay.png"));
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(overlay));
        g.drawImage(overlay, spaceX, spaceY, BOARDWIDTH, BOARDHEIGHT, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

This I would like to save as a BufferedImage, so I don't have to run this method all the time.

So how can I save just this part of my JPanel, without the stuff outside of the chess board? (there will be more painted)

Comment: What is the thing you want to "save"? The chess board?

Comment: Yes, I want to save the chess board. The game is running with a thread, so i want to calculate as little as possible.

Comment: [Writing/Saving an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This I would like to save as a BufferedImage,

Don't know that your need to save the BufferedImage to a file. You can just create a BufferedImage to be used by the application when the application starts. You can then recreate the BufferedImage if any of the user colors change.

You can paint directly to a BufferedImage:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(boardSize, boardSize, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();

// draw the squares onto board

g2d.dispose();
```

Now your createBoard() method should probably return the BufferedImage so it can be used by your application.

Comment: This would be great, but I dont't get it to work. I tryed to use 2 Graphics now, one for the board and one for the rest, but when it comes to the board Graphics, there is a NullPointerException. As I said, I have verry little experience, so do you have any idea, what could be wrong? If you want to, I can show you the whole code. Is there a possibility to upload files?

Comment: @Duke, `I can show you the whole code` - we are not interested in your whole code. We want to see a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. So in your case you are learning a concept of how to draw to a BufferedImage. So to test the concept all you need is the above statements plus something like `g2d.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50)`. Then you can create an `ImageIcon` using the image. Then you can create a `JLabel` and add the label to the frame. So then entire code will be about 15-20 lines of code. Once you learn the basic concept, then you apply the knowledge to your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

You put in certain efforts to put up your question, so lets honor that with some thoughts to get you going.

First of all: you have an empty catch block {}. That is bad practice. This simply eats up any error messages you get. That is not helpful. Either allow that exception to bubble up and stop your application; or at least print its contents - so that you understand what happens.

And given your comment: you **never** now if there will be errors. Especially when doing IO, all sorts of things can go wrong. Please believe me: **empty** catch blocks are **bad** practice; and you should not train yourself to accept them.

Second thought: don't go for that yet. As convenient as it might sound; but saving a background picture doesn't add much value at this point.

You don't need to worry about this code; it is executed once when your application comes up.

So, the real answer here: focus on the features you want to implement; and don't get distracted with [pre-mature optimizations](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil/).

Comment: Thank you for your hint. You're right, it's not necessairy to do this, but i have to draw the overlay image anyway, so why not first save the whole chess board as one image and then draw this instead of letting the thread calculate the chess board all the time? The empty catch block is there because I have to use try catch for avoiding errors, but there wont ever be one. So is there a better possibility then try catch?

Comment: OK ... makes sense. Just wondering: do you allow to resize the board? If so, what should happen then? And btw: your English is excellent.

Comment: Maybe I will. All the size-integers are calculated when starting the game (TILESIZE, spaceY, BOARDHEIGHT...) so actually I think it's possible.

Comment: I know. That is why I only mentioned accepting - because that you can do.
You need to earn 15 rep yourself to acquire upvote rights. I just helped with that a little bit; as I really like your input.